# c# Read an iText document from website

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, itext, geckofx

I'm working on a project to parse peoples transcripts from the IRS.

Here's the link if you want to check it out - http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Get-Transcript

These aren't like the normal PDF forms on the site. When the user signs in through the embedded webbrowser I want my program to take over and read their transcripts.

When I am viewing a transcript in Firefox it shows all the HTML in the developer console, but there is no HTML when in my application(trying both winForms and WPF) browser even with geckofx(29).

Any ideas on how to read these? Or why I can see the HTML in Firefox but not through the application?

I would even be happy if I could download the document and then parse it, but not sure how as the URL is generic and the same for all transcripts.

I can see these are generated with iText, is there a way to get iTextSharp to read from the browser?

Thanks in advance.